# Jasmine custom matcher type definition

Tags: typescript, jasmine, matcher, type-definition, jasmine-matchers

I am trying to add typescript definition to a jasmine matcher [library](https://github.com/MassimoFoti/jasmineMatchers).

I was able to add the matchers for the generic type `T` but now i want to add matchers only to DOM elements.

Digging into the jasmine type definition code I found a similar approach to `ArrayLike` (see [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L85) for the `expect` overload and [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L455-L460) for the `ArrayLikeMatchers`).

So I created a similar one.

```
// Overload the expect
declare function expect<T extends HTMLElement>(actual: T): jasmine.DOMMatchers<T>;

declare namespace jasmine {
    // Augment the standard matchers. This WORKS!
    interface Matchers<T> {
        toBeExtensible(): boolean;
        toBeFrozen(): boolean;
        toBeSealed(): boolean;
        // ... other
    }
    // The matchers for DOM elements. This is NOT working!
    interface DOMMatchers<T> extends Matchers<T> {
        toBeChecked(): boolean;
        toBeDisabled(): boolean;
    }
}
```

But, is not working :(

Given the following code:

```
const div = document.createElement("div");
expect(div).toBeChecked();
```

The type checker is giving me the error:

> [js] Property 'toBeChecked' does not exist on type 'Matchers'.

---

The only solution seems to be adding the `expect` overload **before** the generic `expect` (after the `ArrayLike` overload [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jasmine/index.d.ts#L85)) in the core jasmine library.

But... it is not doable :)

Any hint on how to properly implement a working solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Typescript chooses overloads in declaration order and the very generic `declare function expect<T>(actual: T): jasmine.Matchers<T>;` will come before your overload. You might be able to find some magic ordering using `///` references but I have not been able to get it to work and it would be very brittle.

A better approach would be to add your extra functions right on `Matchers<T>` but constrain `this` to be derived from `Matchers<HTMLElement>`

```
declare namespace jasmine {
    interface Matchers<T> {
        toBeExtensible(): boolean;
        toBeFrozen(): boolean;
        toBeSealed(): boolean;

        // this must be derived from Matchers<HTMLElement>
        toBeDisabled(this: Matchers<HTMLElement>): boolean;
        // or make it generic, with T extending HTMLElement if you really need the actual type for some reason 
        toBeChecked<T extends HTMLElement>(this: Matchers<HTMLElement>): boolean; 
    }
}

// usage
const div = document.createElement("div");
expect(div).toBeChecked(); // ok
expect(10).toBeChecked() // error
```

Comment: Thanks @Titian, that worked like a charm!

In the end i used: `toBeChecked<T extends HTMLElement>( this: Matchers<T>): boolean;`